# Using different symbol than vertical line

Tags: python, json

i have this json requests. This one is correct:

```
import requests

data={"transfer":"aa|bb|cc|dd|ee"}
response = requests.post('https://example.com',json=data).json()
```

but i need to use it a different way. I can't use "**|**" in post data and get the same result.
This one is not working:

```
import requests
import urllib

data2 = urllib.quote("aa|bb|cc|dd|ee")
data={"transfer":data2}
response = requests.post('https://example.com',json=data).json()
```

Is there any chance to replace, quote or something to do with "**|**" to get correct result?

Comment: why do you want to encode it beforehand? That will encode the data twice. Of course you don't get same result.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question. Why not just use the first code block?

Comment: Because sometimes i have to use:     url | post_data | header, so it'should be only 3 "**|**", when i have post_data like in first block i got error. So, that's why i'm asking if it's possible to use a different symbol than "**|**".